# A better dialogue for own-question answer?

Tags: discussion

After waiting couple hours for an answer to a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23537/mismatch-between-2-69-and-2-72-interfaces-for-video-sequence-editor-window) I posted on the Blender site, I found the answer myself and decided to post it.  During that process, I was asked a pointed question ("do you **really** want to do this").  I thought answering your own question is not only possible but encouraged.  Is the heavy-handed approach really necessary?

Here's the sequence:

[image]

Strikes me as somewhat counterintuitive: Answer Your Question... OK, I will.  Immediately afterwards, "Are you sure you want to answer your question?"

Comment: It's important here that you look at the rest of the dialog. It's essentially there to try and prevent users from posting follow-up comments/responses or clarifications of their questions as answers.

Comment: Who asked the "pointed question" discouraging you from answering your own question? It seams that user needs to learn something about the SE system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're asked is the following:

> [image: Self-answer dialog]

If you keep on reading past the large title, it suggests that comments should be posted as a comment, and questions themselves can be edited to update them.

There are plenty of users who aren't used to the Stack Exchange Q&A format. They are used to forums where you respond to others or clarify your own content by creating a new post. We'd like to prevent that from happening. (It's annoying to deal with for us regulars, and won't be a positive experience for the poster either).

So that's all there is to that dialog. If you have a great self-answer, by all means post it. We just want to make sure that you're not making a mistake.

Comment: At the time I was answering my question, there were *no* answers.  So, I could not be responding to an answer.  And as a longtime stackoverflow user, I know how to edit questions, and could not be confusing the issue.

Comment: Certainly. You apparently are very aware of how this thing works. Great. :) But unfortunately that's not the case for a lot of users. So better be safe than sorry there. You could put in a new feature request somewhere to make it context sensitive, but I'd give that one a "meh".

Comment: By the way, I initially did not read past the large title, because all I was concerned about at that instance was not forgetting what I was going to post! ;-)

Comment: Haha, can't say that hasn't happened to me before. Especially in a dialog that "doesn't apply to me". Clickety-click. But yeah, overall I can deal with an extra dialog if that prevents me from having to clean up the mess of others afterwards. :)

Comment: I wonder how difficult it would be to do a context-sensitive check.  I am not familiar w/ the Stack Exchange API, and I am sure the current number of answers to a question would be available, but how easily, don't know.  Also, if a user like myself does not initially read past the large title, then that in itself should be a comment on the UI experience, don't you think? Thanks.

Comment: Hang out with us on Meta SE and Meta SO for a while. You'll realize soon that people (even those with the best intentions) don't read stuff, no matter how well you prepare it for them or how in-your-face you put it. :D But that said, if you have particular suggestions to improve experiences, by all means see if they have been suggested before, and if not then suggest them.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with answering your own question. In fact it is encouraged.

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8560/apply-vertex-paint-to-a-vertex#comment13978_8560) comment discussion shows it well.

[Self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
[It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions)
[Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12513/278094)
[Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/278094)

That warning is similar to the "Are you sure you want to add another answer?" warning. Just a reminder box letting users know that what you are about to do *may* not be the best format.

Comment: And of course there's [the introduction of the feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are allowed to answer your own question if you have found a solution.

That doesn't mean that people won't downvote it if they think that it's not a good answer.  They're going to evaluate its quality just like they will every other answer, and provide the appropriate feedback.

Comment: My question here does not concern downvotes.  I really don't understand why you would bring that up.  I am questioning the tone and wording of the dialogue shown to the user during the process of a self-answer.